# HijriCalendar for WinRT (Windows 8 Metro)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

is there any implementation of `HijriCalendar` for WinRT (or `.Net for Metro apps`) out there?

It seems that Microsoft removed all `System.Globalization` calendars from `.Net for Metro apps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at it this week. All calendars exist in RTM version and you can see them in Locals and Auto windows of VS2012 while debugging. I.e. there are GregorianCalendar, Hijri, etc.., but all these stuff is internal and you can't access it even via reflection

Comment: yes, I tried to get some property value from GregorianCalendar class with reflection. You can enumerate properties, even get PropertyInfo, but you can't get property value, it fires something like access denied exception (don't remember exact spelling).

Comment: I'm not sure what MS think about that, maybe they are thinking about using new Globalization classes introduced in Metro and so they hide the old stuff. Or maybe they can consider adding globalization classes back as a feature request.

Comment: that's sad. can we extract the codes somehow and use them in code? as I recall it was possible to access .Net source codes.

Comment: it depends on what you want from this code. In my case it useless, as I need to enumerate available calendars from the current culture and select one which is more appropriate. Custom code won't help me.

Comment: that will work for me, but I'm worried about its license. do you how its license works?

Comment: it should not be a problem, but I don't know for sure. Try to ask that in a separate question